# AWS QuickSight and cardinality

Tags: amazon-web-services, powerbi, amazon-quicksight, cardinality

As a Power BI user I know that I can, in the modeling tab when joining two tables, select the cardinality of the relationship (many:one, one:many, many:many, or  one:one) and change the direction. I know that you can do joins in QuickSight but is there a cardinality option?

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for the same, and came to know QuickSight does not provide the relationship or cardinality feature like PowerBI.